# Is it possible to modify content in the invoice template based on contribution currency?

Tags: civicontribute, currency

We have a client who has membership bases in two countries (e.g. Australia and New Zealand). I understand that we can have two membership organisations to manage the two membership bases.

The issue seems to be that the invoice template, for contributions, shows the Name, Address, Currency etc for the primary domain.

Due to legal requirements as to what should appear on an invoice we need to be able to change the invoice content a little to reflect the address of the member organisation, rather than the primary organisation.

Is it possible to have the content of the Invoice change to reflect the membership organisation? Maybe by detecting the Contribution Currency and adjusting the invoice template markup to suit?

The API explorer is throwing an error for me, when trying to search for Contributions, so it's hard to know where to start on this one.

Comment: as the api explorer, can you create a separate issue with a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change the invoice value based the currency

To start with please create an extension using

hook_civicrm_tokens and hook_civicrm_tokenValues

Make the necessary changes in Message Templates -> System Workflow Message -> Contribution Invoice Receipt

This will allow you to make the changes in Invoice